# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://......login' from origin 'https://.....r.in' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have hosted laravel and angular application on server it was working before but now it is throwing below error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://......login' from origin
> 'https://.....r.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I have created CORS middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> api route file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api','cors','prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);    
});
```

> Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];
}
```

Any solution is highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Remove the string `'cors'` from the route group and add the class CORS::class in your `Kernel.php` under the api middleware though I do recommend using https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors (will need to find the correct version to use depending on your Laravel version though)

Comment: @apokryfos I have added kernel.php in my question please check i have added cors middleware but still the same issue, this was working previously but not it is throwing this error

Comment: I suggested adding the middleware in your `Kernel.php` in `'api'` array (which is under the `$middlewareGroups`). You have added it in the middleware array and named it `'guest'` which will overwrite the other guest middleware and not actually work because you don't use it

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the browser, so you need to have those headers on the response. For this, you need to have middleware for the response, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-and-responses

```
$response = $next($request);

// add headers to response here

return $response;
```

**Additional info:**

You need to edit your CORS middleware.
it will look like this:

```
$response = $next($request);
if ($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
    return $response;
}

$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');

return $response;
```

You made a few typos:
**Acess** should be **Access**

and in the Kernel.php you have
`'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,`
But I think it should be
`'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,`
because you use **cors** name in your routes.

**Updated again:**

The second header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` instead of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

It might throw another error about allowed methods(because it said preflight request) so you will need to fix it by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

**Regarding the error:**

*getting Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://beta-XXX/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://XXXXX.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response*

It says that the preflight request (in that case, it is OPTIONS, not GET or POST) doesn't allow Content-Type. This is because it is not applied to this kind of method. In that case, there should be a new route under middleware `cors` like
`Route::options('/login', ...);`
But since you will need it in other places as well, then it is better to customize the CORS middleware for preflight requests through the entire application by adding your Cors middleware into the `$middleware` array (then it will run for every request). Please try/test that if needed. Then it might be that it is needed only for OPTIONS requests, if it is true then I'd add(I've modified it in the above snippet as well)

```
if ($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
    return $response;
}
```

**WARNING/NOTICE:**
if you make it to work, the next step would be to make sure that you specify what origins are allowed in production. Instead of `*`, you should have a list of domains that are allowed to use it (or even better you can respond with `*` only for allowed hosts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, In which middleware should i change?

Comment: updated CORS middleware `$response = $next($request);
$response->header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$response->header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
return $next($response);` but getting same issue

Comment: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://beta-XXX.in/api/auth/login. (Reason: header ‘authorization’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).` getting this error i have updated your code

Comment: tried but getting `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://beta-XXX/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://XXXXX.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response` this error

Comment: I have changed the CORS middleware but still getting same CORS error i have also talked with hosting support there is no port which is blocked any reason why i'm facing this issue

Comment: @user3653474 have you added your Cors middleware into $middleware array as well?